# Typo in datatype of sqlite3 but still work, why?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I made in typo in the datatype of sqlite3 carelessly when writing the `schema.sql`:

```
create table xxx(
    id integer primary key autoincrement not null,
    num integet
)
```

As you can see, `integet` should be `integer`, but it still works which means I can insert data into it. Why? And how can I correct it to `integer` without break the database?

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your question. You want to modify the datatype in-place on a live database? Or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation for [the Python `sqlite3` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite-and-python-types) and [the database itself](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname) both explain, sqlite3 is untyped. You can insert string values into an `INTEGER` column, or integer values into a `VARCHAR` column.

However, sqlite has a feature called "column affinity", where it will try to treat parameters numerically if the column type is INTEGER, etc. And the Python module tries to map each of the sqlite types to Python types, so if sqlite gives it an INTEGER column, Python will map it to an integral type.

As the respective documentation explains:

> If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned INTEGER affinity.
>
> INTEGER   int or long, depending on size

The comparison is case-insensitive. Anything that does not match any of the rules will be treated as `NUMERIC`, which Python will treat as `str`/`bytes`/`buffer` (depending on your version).

So, to sqlite itself, `integet` matches the rules for `INTEGER`, so, you can store integral values and retrieve them as integers. (Of course you can also still store `'abc'`, and you'll get it back as a string.) And Python will see this as an `INTEGER` column, and therefore read values as `int` when possible.

---

As for the last part of your question, sqlite3 does not provide any way to change the type of a column after it's been created. In fact, the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) command only allows adding new columns or constraints, or renaming tables.

If you need to modify a live database, what you need to do is create a new table with the right columns, copy everything over, delete the old table, and rename the new table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE yyy(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, num INTEGER)
INSERT INTO yyy SELECT * FROM xxx
DROP TABLE xxx
ALTER TABLE yyy RENAME TO xxx
```

Any string values you inserted into the old table will be copied over—and every subsequent time you fetch them, because the column type is `INTEGER`, Python will try convert to `int` if possible, instead of leaving them as `bytes` or `str`.

Comment: This is not how the [determination of column affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname) works.

Comment: @CL.: Ah, you're right, Python doesn't get involved until after sqlite does. Let me update the answer.

Comment: I found what I really need: 

 `echo '.dump' | sqlite3 xxx >xxx.dump`
and then edit `xxx.dump` , correct `integet` to  `integer`,save the file. Finally, `cat xxx.dump | sqlite3 yyy`. What I care about is the table schema.

Answer (score -1):

SQLite is forgiving to the point of silliness. You can create a column of type "wibble". This CREATE TABLE statement works in SQLite.

```
create table wibble (wibble wibble);
```

And you can insert into it, too.

```
insert into wibble values ('wibble');
```